# DC Promo With DNS Windows 2008R2 Resulting In Weird Network Error

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, reverse-dns

I am preparing for DC domain migration in which I am encounter some error that I had never encounter in my VM testing environment.

Note: This is the first time I am setting up an active DC with DNS. Prior experience only with VM, on testing environment.

Network Info: All my servers (Including the new DC) are in a Trusted zone, behind a firewall. There are other zones such as Wireless Zone and User Zone, as well as DMZ. Each has their own subnet.

DC/DNS Info: Set a static IP address with the correct gateway, DNS pointing to itself. No Antivirus install, yet.

After I successfully did a DCpromo.exe, it prompts me for DNS and I follow the wizard through.

Here's where the problem occur. After the DC/DNS server restarted itself, I can no longer ping or RDP from user zone.

Weirdly, when I try to ping devices from the DC/DNS server to other devices in the DMZ, it return the following:

Reply from (DC/DNS IP): Destination host unreachable
nslookup is pointing to itself

I am unable to ping 8.8.8.8 as well as ping to any other LAN subnet network.

However, I am able to ping and RDP from the DC/DNS to other servers in the same Trusted zone, same subnet with no issue.

After hours of being on Google, I have done the following:

1) Turn off firewall.
2) Restart Netlogon service.
3) net stop dns, Flush DNS,net start dns, ipconfig /registerdns
4) Restart Server

Why is this so?

What did I miss out?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question above is because of DNS settings, whereby the FQDN of the domain controller is not the same as what was configured in the DNS.

TL;DR > Solution: Change the name of the server before setting up DNS.

## Rookie_Mistake.